# How to Parse a JSON with Swift on IOS, sent from a PHP service script?

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I'm having trouble parsing a JSON, sent from a PHP script, on IOS using swift. I just started learning IOS development this week and also had never worked with JSON before so any help would be greatly appreciated on parsing this correctly. I'm sending a result from a mysql query as a JSON to the app. Here is my swift code and the error log in which you can see the object received by the http service.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let secondViewController:VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "myscriptaddress");

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

            let postString = "condition=" + String(currentval);

            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

            secondViewController.mystring = "getting ready"

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                guard data != nil else {
                    print("no data found: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                        print("Success")

                    } else {
                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")

                    }
                } catch let parseError {
                    print(parseError)
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Error can't parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")

                }
            }

            task.resume()
}
```

And now the error log:

```
Error could not parse JSON: Optional([{"unidad":"sanfrancisco","capacidad":"15","uso":"5","telefono":"num"},{"unidad":"pediatricouniversitario","capacidad":"15","uso":"5","telefono":"num"},{"unidad":"sanjorge","capacidad":"15","uso":"7","telefono":"num"},{"unidad":"himacaguas","capacidad":"20","uso":"4","telefono":"num"},{"unidad":"himabayamon","capacidad":"20","uso":"8","telefono":"num"},{"unidad":"sanlucas","capacidad":"10","uso":"8","telefono":"num"},{"unidad":"auxiliomutuo","capacidad":"15","uso":"11","telefono":"num"}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its failing to unwrap the JSON data as a dictionary type. The JSON string provided is an array of objects.

Try this in your JSONObjectWithData call:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String : AnyObject]]
```